# How to focus on a new Emacs frame in Windows

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to get a focus for a new Emacs frame when it has been raised from outside of Emacs (for example, from `emacsclient` or `edit-server`)? Currently, the new frame get input focus, but not *display* focus, i.e. you enter text, but it's somewhere behind other windows (in Windows OS terminology). There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636694/emacsclient-window-focus) and it's marked as answered, but with no solution, though.

Emacs 23.3.

Answer (score 4):

The function `raise-frame` can bring a frame to the front.

Comment: This function gives the same result which I described. The frame gets the input focus, but does not become 'selected' by the Explorer. I guess, `raise-frame` is called already by default on a frame creation.

Comment: Ask the guys on [emacs devel](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel) if there is some other way to do it or it's a bug.

Comment: (raise-frame) just helped me on GNU/Linux. I don’t know whether it works on Windows, but it solved my own problem: I now start my emacsclient with `emacsclient -ce \"(raise-frame)\"`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What version of Emacs are you running?  I used put in gnuserv-visit-hook:

```
(select-frame-set-input-focus (window-frame (selected-window)))
```

But with Emacs 23, it's the default controlled by `server-raise-frame`.

Comment: Emacs 23.3 (it is the same even from a fresh start (OS, empty .emacs)). I tried your solution—the issue persists. `server-raise-frame` is `t`.

Answer (score 0):

See also function `select-frame-set-input-focus`:

*"Select FRAME, raise it, and set input focus, if possible."*